# AJAX : how to send backslash in data?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, backslash, slash

I'm trying to send php code via ajax in order to save it in a file.
But when I send something like:

```
...$buffer = "if(\$_POST){".chr(13).chr(10);...
```

The backslash disappeared!

This is the code I'm using:

```
$.post('save.php', {
            "c":  window[currentCode].getValue(),
            processData: false,
            "f": fileName
        }, function(data){
           ....
        });
        return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to escape the backslash for it to have its literal meaning.  Just double it and then add one more to properly escape the `$`.  `if(\\\$_POST)`

Answer (score 2):

```
"if(\\\$_POST){"
```

two more backslashes in front.

Comment: Thank you. 
Solution:

    window[currentCode].getValue().replace(/\\/g,"\\\\")

Comment: That might have some unforseen consequences in other areas of your code.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused on what your issue is at this point, so I'm not sure how to help, but here's a couple references to get you going.  [the php manual on strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) and [the php manual on str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an Ajax issue; you misunderstood escaping. In PHP, `"\$"` evaluates to string `$` because the backslash has just escaping function (you'd also see just `$` if you'd open save.php in browser). To write literal `\$`, you first need to write `\` string (but backslash also has to be escaped, so we have `"\\"`, then write `$` as `"\$"`. So doing

```
$buffer = "...\\\$_POST...";
```

produces expected results.

Also see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Answer (score 0):

I'm still having a problem, when I need to edit files with regular expressions in javascript like this:

```
function _basename(path) {
    return path.replace(/\\\\/g,'/').replace( /.*\\//, '' );
}

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

The function I used in order to edit .php files, corrupt my javascript code. 
I need a way to edit code, that I can use for all languajes.

EDIT:
I'm having this problem just in a Linux server not in windows

Help please!

Comment: In Linux the extra backslash is added twice!